# Oscar Peterson I've got it bad and that ain't good bar 10: Dm7 flat 5 flat 11?

Tags: chords, jazz

This chord is played over a bass player on a d, it's coming right after a dm7.

From the bottom up

F# Ab C F Ab

Is that F# a flat 11? Is the Ab a flat 5 or a sharp 11?

Or is this a passing chord that is actually a d7 sharp 9 flat 5?

This is in Oscar Peterson's I've got it bad and that ain't good, last chord of bar 10. (The slower version..)

Comment: 1. What recording? 2. What is the question?

Comment: Hi Dan - welcome. Can you please read our [about] and [ask] page then edit your question to include things like a link to the recording, and to focus more on the way to describe or spell a chord than identifying a specific chord (as that would be off topic) thank you

Answer (score 2):

First off, the chord is a D chord so the F# is the 3rd, not a b11. The term b11 is very rare, it’s more theoretical than practical.

At face value the logical name for the chord you spelled out would be D7#9#11 (spelled with G#’s for the #11). It could also be called a D7b5#9 but b5 MIGHT imply playing the Ab lower in the voicing, closer to the root/bass note.

However I’m hearing just F#-C-E#, a regular D7#9. It’s function is a dominant of the next chord. The chord is extremely brief, only a swing 8th note in duration but he does proceed to resolve the entire voicing down a semitone to a G13, F-B-E (the G played by the bass) and then go back and forth between the two voicings over the G in the bass.

This question might be closed but I hope it isn’t because it is less about identifying and more about how to properly spell out a chord.

Comment: +1 for the answer, and if I could, another for your last para. (Although spelling out a specific chord would contravene the rules.) However, maybe there's an opportunity to ask without using a specific example, with a little editing.

Comment: There's the upside that a closed question with an upvoted answer will in fact hang around, if not specifically voted for deletion - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-duplicate-question It still might be better to try shape up the question to better conform, if anyone feels up to the task.